# get file info from assets folder and create

Tags: angular, audio, angular9

I'm setting up a music player in angular. I'm using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-audio-player package. My aim is to archive a Playlist generated by all files in my angular assets/mp3 folder. Right now I have to know every filename to create the list manually.

It would be great to just put new audio files in this folder and the playlist updates himself.

This is the array for the audio player

```
msaapPlaylist: Track[] = [
{
  title: 'Audio One Title',
  link: 'Link to Audio One URL'
},
{
  title: 'Audio Two Title',
  link: 'Link to Audio Two URL'
},
{
  title: 'Audio Three Title',
  link: 'Link to Audio Three URL'
},
  ];
```

I need to create an automatic **title** info reader for each file in the assets folder and store this info in this array.  But how do I get the info?

Best,
peter

Comment: You need to create an API that will return the list of files in the folder

Comment: You can't access file system using javascript, angular or any other fron-end frameworks. You need a server side language to read file system and through API get file names